# ORACLE 19.3 : 2 instances on same machine : ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have installed 2 oracle 19.3 databases instances on the same server.

The first installed DB instance one has the following specifications :

```
[oracle@ora19 ~]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME 
/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1

[oracle@ora19 ~]$ echo $ORACLE_SID 
oradb
```

I can connect to this one whitout problem :

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Nov 25 08:31:37 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connecte a :
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

The second installed DB instance one has the following specifications :

```
[oracle@ora19 bin]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME 
/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/rman/

[oracle@ora19 bin]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
rmandb
```

I am encountering an ORA-12547 error when I try to connect to this DB :

```
[oracle@ora19 bin]$ ./sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Nov 25 08:32:23 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


Enter user-name:
```

The 2 databases process are running as usually :

```
[oracle@ora19 bin]$ ps -edf | grep 'pmon\|lgr\|ckpt'
    grid      3167     1  0 nov.24 ?       00:00:03 asm_pmon_+ASM
    grid      3197     1  0 nov.24 ?       00:00:02 asm_ckpt_+ASM
    oracle    3295     1  0 nov.24 ?       00:00:04 ora_pmon_oradb
    oracle    3349     1  0 nov.24 ?       00:00:15 ora_ckpt_oradb
    oracle   12154  5055  0 08:39 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pmon\|lgr\|ckpt
    oracle   24177     1  0 nov.24 ?       00:00:04 ora_pmon_rmandb
    oracle   24217     1  0 nov.24 ?       00:00:16 ora_ckpt_rmandb
```

idem with srvctl check:

```
[oracle@ora19 bin]$ srvctl status database -db rmandb
```

=> ok

```
[oracle@ora19 bin]$ srvctl status database -db oradb
```

=> ok

listener status:

```
[oracle@ora19 bin]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 25-NOV-2022 09:07:50

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                24-NOV-2022 13:04:31
Uptime                    0 days 14 hr. 3 min. 19 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/19.0.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/grid/diag/tnslsnr/ora19/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ora19.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=ora19.localdomain)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/admin/oradb/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=ora19.localdomain)(PORT=5501))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/admin/rmandb/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_DATADG" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_FRADG" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_OCRDG" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_RMANDG" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "oradb.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "oradb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "oradbXDB.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "oradb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "rmandb.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "rmandb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "rmandbXDB.localdomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "rmandb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Are there special considerations when running 2 oracle instances on the same machine ?

Comment: Unless you have TWO_TASK set you're using a bequeath connection, so the listener shouldn't really be relevant. When you try to switch between the databases are you only changing the two variables you showed, or also PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc.? Did you run `oraenv` to set everything up properly? Is there anything else in your `env` output that includes `db_1`?

Comment: what do you mean by setting TWO_TASK?

`source /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/rman/bin/oraenv` makes it work!

Comment: Good - so something was still pointing to the wrong ORACLE_HOME, and running that (re)set everything properly. TWO_TASK sets a default TNS alias to use; don't worry about it, you don't have it set so it's using a bequeath connection not TNS (making the TNS- error confusing). Really I was just pointing out that the listener info wasn't likely to be relevant for how you were connecting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I tried to connect to my Oracle DB running in a container via sqlplus on my local machine.

```bash
> sqlplus <user>/<pass>@//localhost:1522/xe

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Mar 15 16:34:16 2024
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


Enter user-name: _
```

In my case it was related to an active VPN Connection. As soon as I disconnected, it worked just fine.

Hope that helps somebody :)